# Help with identifying a character

Tags: translation, words

Can anyone tell me what this character means?

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you're asking on the right site (Japanese.SE and not Chinese.SE)?

Comment: [你](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/你), this character may have been used in Japanese but it is way more common in Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

That's the first character in the well-known Mandarin Chinese greeting "nĭ hăo" (你好). 你 means "you." I don't remember ever seeing it in a Japanese context, and jisho.org returns no words containing it.

Edit: tried searching *你, and got one result - 玫瑰玫瑰我愛你, which is a Chinese song from the 1940's which means "Rose, Rose, I love you." *你* also has no results.